# Convert transparent to white in GraphicsMagick Nodejs

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

Using gm with nodejs, if I convert a png with transparent pixels to jpg, the transparent pixels are automatically converted to black. How do I change this to convert the transparent pixels to white instead?

```
gm(image)
.quality(100)
.trim()
.setFormat("jpg")
.interlace("Line")
.resize(650, null)
.noProfile()
```

Comment: Try setting the background colour to white first since JPEGs do not support transparency.

Comment: I thought so, but how do I do that? I tried adding .background("rgb(255,255,255)") first but it had no effect.

Comment: Not sure what is going on with this, but try `.fill("yellow")` then `.opaque("none")`

Comment: That appears to change completely black pixels to yellow. Getting closer though. I tried several possible color codes for transparent within the opaque function including rgba(0,0,0,0), #00ffffff, #00000000 and none seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to add .flatten()